# Getting rid of lengthy switch statement in favor of a loop or other conditional statement?

Tags: arrays, loops, switch-statement, variable-assignment, conditional-statements

Alright, so I asked a question like this a long while ago, but I didn't quite get the answer I was looking for. Mainly probably because I didn't include enough code. I'll paste it first then explain after.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone/Notification");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Ringtone/Notification") {
        function1(item.getItemId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// detect button clicked, save as a ringtone using strings.xml
public boolean function1(int ressound) {

    String soundname = "";


    switch (ressound) {
        case R.id.button01:
            ressound = R.raw.sound01;
            soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote01));
            break;
        case R.id.button02:
            ressound = R.raw.sound02;
            soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote02));
            break;
        case R.id.button03:
            ressound = R.raw.sound03;
            soundname = (this.getString(R.string.app_name)) + " - " + (this.getString(R.string.quote03));
            break;
    }
```

My problem lies with the switch statement. Eventually, there are going to be a LOT of buttons/quotes/sounds that all match by the numbers after "button" "sound" and "quote". In my last app, it got very, very tedious and tiresome to go through and copy/paste up to 50 switch cases at a time and go through and edit each one to be specific to button10/sound10/quote10, button11/sound11/quote11, etc.

I've tried to play around with some stuff, but can't seem to get it to work.

If it helps, I have them all in arrays like this (for a purpose currently elsewhere in the code):

```
final int[] buttonIds = {R.id.button01, R.id.button02, R.id.button03,
        R.id.button04, R.id.button05, R.id.button06,
        R.id.button07, R.id.button08, R.id.button09,
        R.id.button10};

final int[] soundIds = {R.raw.sound01, R.raw.sound02, R.raw.sound03,
        R.raw.sound04, R.raw.sound05, R.raw.sound06,
        R.raw.sound07, R.raw.sound08, R.raw.sound09,
        R.raw.sound10};

final int[] stringIds = {R.string.quote01, R.string.quote02, R.string.quote03,
        R.string.quote04, R.string.quote05, R.string.quote06,
        R.string.quote07, R.string.quote08, R.string.quote09,
        R.string.quote10};
```

Thank you in advanced for your help and guidance!

Comment: If the data in the arrays is aligned (button1 is in same position in the array as sound1 ...) then just find the index of the button that was clicked and use the items from the other arrays at the same location.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do. But I can't do it with a switch statement since it needs to be a constant value, and I'm having trouble setting up a different conditional statement where I can actually use the arrays :/